# how to create a transparent background for the Launcher application icon

Tags: android

How can I change the background image of the launcher icon in the "image assets" section and drop it off the white background?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate ic_launcher with this web:

[ic_launcher generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher)

You can remove the background with [pixlr](http://pixlr.com/editor)

**Go to the magic selector and click to select logo and ctrl+x and create new file in pixlr and paste**

Answer (score 0):

you can use GIMP to remove the background of the image and make it transparent just save as a PNG or GIF. you can also use javascript and load the picture into canvas and remove all white pixels